# Adding 2 URLs for UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: objective-c

User can share by tapping Share button and I've implemented whatsapp url so documentation interaction controller would have whatsapp icon but I'd also like to have instagram in it and not having to have another button for instagram.

How can I do this?

Below code does not work -

```
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL secondURL:(NSURL*) file2URL

                                           usingDelegate: (id ) interactionDelegate {



self.documentationInteractionController =

[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: file2URL];

self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;



return self.documentationInteractionController;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't work! take a look at these lines:

```
self.documentationInteractionController =

[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL]; // Line 1
[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: file2URL]; // Line 2
```

You are setting `fileURL` as `self.documentationInteractionController` on line 1 and in line 2 you are not doing anything, I mean you are creating a document but not assigning to anything. your cue should be that semicolon at the end of line 1! `documentationInteractionController` is a property you can set for one object only. you should probably create another document for Instagram.

Comment: So there's no way to give users options to choose from when showing documentation interaction controller..? I just thought I'd seen it somewhere... Maybe I never saw it and just imagined it..